# Is it possible to allocate DNS permissions for a / domain extension?

Tags: dns, cloudflare

Sorry for the choppy title.

Ultimately, I have an app which needs to be integrated into a website on the parent domain, however, it also needs to be isolated from the already existing parent domain website.

Ideally, I need a way to provide DNS permissions just for parentdomain.com/admin/ for example, so that my website is hosted on the /admin extension of the domain and is isolated from the root parent domain itself.

Is this possible? Where can I learn more about it?

Comment: DNS is about domain-level settings.  That doesn't make any sense.

Comment: I think https://serverfault.com/ would be a better choice for this question, as you don't appear to be talking about programming.

Comment: This is not possible with DNS. DNS does not apply to a sub-folder.

Answer (score 0):

DNS cannot work at a subfolder level, you need to route your traffic through a subdomain. One example is you can create an alias for the site through `admin.parentdomain.com` and visit `admin.parentdomain.com/admin` through there; but redirect anyone away who tries to directly access the subdomain.